# How to move down to a parent directory in Python?

Tags: python

The following code in Python gives me the current path.

```
import os
DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

How can I now use the variable `DIR` to go down one more directory? I don't want to change the value of `DIR` as it is used elsewhere.

I have tried this:

```
DIR + "../path/"
```

But it does not seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call one more `dirname`:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(DIR), 'path')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import os.path
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(DIR, os.pardir)))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you join a path via '+' you have to add a 'r':

```
path = r'C:/home/' + r'user/dekstop'
```

or write double backslashes:

```
path = 'C://home//' + 'user//dekstop'
```

Anyway you should never use that!

That's the best way:

```
import os
path = os.path.join('C:/home/', 'user/dekstop')
```